# Arc by center point in PostGIS does not fit the circle

Tags: postgis, coordinate-system

I'd like to store a GML ArcByCenterPoint in PostGIS. I can work out the start, middle and end points required by the `CIRCULARSTRING` type and all seems to be OK, except that when I visualise the arc it does not fit the circle that it's supposed to be part of.

Data (in lon/lat format):

```
Circle centre point: 29.59444 40.26333
Radius:              18 NM (27780 M)
Arc start point:     29.89250 40.36667
Arc end point:       29.27528 40.31667
Arc middle points:   29.560000 40.511667 (counter-clockwise)
                     29.628611 40.015000 (clockwise)
```

SQL statements to insert the geometries. Note that I'm using `ST_CurveToLine` here, because I don't know of anything that can visualise a `CIRCULARSTRING` directly.

```
-- The arcs going both ways between the same start and end points
INSERT INTO test (test) VALUES (ST_SetSRID(ST_CurveToLine('CIRCULARSTRING(29.8925 40.36667,29.560000 40.511667,29.27528 40.31667)'), 4326));
INSERT INTO test (test) VALUES (ST_SetSRID(ST_CurveToLine('CIRCULARSTRING(29.8925 40.36667,29.628611 40.015000,29.27528 40.31667)'), 4326));

-- The full circle
INSERT INTO test (test) VALUES (ST_Buffer(ST_GeogFromText('POINT(29.59444 40.26333)'), 15 * 1852)::geometry);
```

Here is what the result looks like in Google Earth:

[image: The resulting shapes]

The arcs are in red and the lines from the center point to the start and end points are in blue. The arcs do touch the circle at 3 points, so it would appear that the coordinates were calculated correctly (or at least close). But the shape of both arcs is wrong - as you can see, they don't quite follow the circle.

Can anyone suggest what's going wrong here? Is either the `CIRCULARSTRING` type or the `ST_CurveToLine` function not doing what I expect? I'd love to take `ST_CurveToLine` out of the equation and visualise the `CIRCULARSTRING` directly, but I don't know of any way to do that.

**Edit:** I finally gave up on this approach and approximated the arc in a different way: [Storing GML surface in PostGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/16481/storing-gml-surface-in-postgis)

Comment: you are viewing lat/lon. A circle is not a circle shown on lat lon. It will always be stretched tall. because the longitudes get more narrow the further north you go. either you have a circle measured strangley on the ground or you have the ground stretched to map flat.

Comment: Hmm, when I visualise it with GeoServer the circle is stretched wide. Does that mean I'm generating the circle incorrect? I'm using ST_Buffer, as shown above.

Comment: It depends on what your circle is representing. if it represents a radius measured on the ground you should coerce the data into an equal area coordinate system. take a look at the difference between geographic coordinate systmes and projected coordinate systems (google).

Comment: @Brad Equal area will almost always distort circles, too.  For checking shapes of smallish features (i.e., having extents less than a few degrees), use conformal projections.

Comment: Thanks whuber - I knew I was off to some degree. When I wrote that. It was late/early - but I should have realized my stateplane systems are all in lambert conformal. @RealityExists the point whuber makes is that using a local crs will get you the most accuracy "on-the-ground".

Comment: I tried using SRID 999036 (which is what _ST_BestSRID() returns) to calculate the points. The result are pretty much the same. Do you think the points of the CIRCULARSTRING are incorrect, though? They do touch the circle generated by ST_Buffer, so I assume they're OK.

Yes, it must be a projection issue and I feel like I'm missing something obvious, but I just don't know what it is.